# Links in a single page wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hyperlink, wordpress-theming

I am building a single page WordPress theme (index.php including header.php and footer.php)

the navigation inside the site is done by jquery div hiding and showing...

as a result,the url of the page do not change, but i want to make it possible so people can share links of specific sections (or states) and bookmark, and have back-button functionality working. how that can be done?

Comment: i heard that i can achieve this by using Hashbangs, or html5 push state... but i have no idea how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [deep linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking).

[jQuery Address*](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) its a plugin for deep linking, with crossbrowser support.

*Github itself has the functionality you are looking for, check the slide transitions while browsing the source of a project. Although github's deep linking [only works with the History API](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider).

Comment: Yep, another method is to use `History API` for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashtags with your links :

HTML :

```
<a href='#sectionOne'>SectionOne</a>
<a href='#sectionTwo'>SectionTwo</a>

<section id='sectionOne'>Hey there, I'm section One</section>
<section id='sectionTwo'>Hey there, I'm section Two</section>
```

CSS :

```
section {
  display: none;
}

section:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Clicking on your link will create a url in your browser that ends with `#sectionOne` which is convinient for bookmarking. Also when you put `:target` selector in CSS that specific `#sectionOne` will be visible, according to your CSS :

Demo : http://jsbin.com/ogodeg/1

Comment: this is good, but it does not help me out with the jquery animations, and states... but thanks anyway!